# Plotly autoscale bug

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

Hello fellow developers,

I'm having some issues with Plotly in my JavaScript application. I have a graph that is fed with data at a rate of one time per second. Naturally, after some time, the x-axis gets too long, and Plotly decides to show only the last few hundred (I will call it the tail-view). That's totally fine, for if I want to see the whole plot I could just click the Autoscale button.

However, it doesn't seem to be working. i mean, it does work, but only for a second (usually less), and it collapses once again into the tail-view. Since I can't put a video here, I will show it in a sequence of three pictures:

**Picture 1** - Tail-view that Plotly creates (with x-axis showing only the previous 500 or so seconds)

[image: Graph before autoscale]

**Picture 2** - That's the whole-view of the graph right after I click the Autoscale button (this also happens with the Reset Axes button). That's what I want, but the issue is that it only stays that way for a very brief period, usually less than 1 second.

[image: Graph right after autoscale is clicked]

**Picture 3** - Graph collapsed to tail-view shortly after I click the Autoscale button

[image: Graph back to compressed after less than one second]

All that said, I wonder if there's a way to fix this issue. I gave the Autoscale example, but it also happens with Reset Axis, and honestly with any other tool that allows me to zoom in/out and pan through the graph - no matter what I do, it almost immediately collapses into the tail-view again. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: Can you give us a sample block of code for us to recreate the issue?